# How to load all sql output data into html table

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

It is a simple email blast program which I build 
I stuck in receiving data in a loop.
I want to print all the data from the result but i can able to print last data in the result.

Here is my code:

```
var mailer = require("nodemailer"),
    config = require('./config'),
    redshiftClient = require('./redshift.js'),
    sql = require('./main');

var smtpTransport = mailer.createTransport({
    service: "Outlook",
    auth: {
        user: config.user,
        pass: config.passwd
    }
});
console.log("Application started at : "+ new Date().getTime())
sql.log();
redshiftClient.query(getQuery())
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log("Query executed at " + new Date().getTime())
        var element = data.rows[index];
        for (let index = 0; index < data.rows.length; index++) {
            var element = data.rows[index];
            var mail = {
                from: 'xxxxxxx@outlook.com',
                to: 'xxxxx@gmail.co.in',
                subject: `Daily AWS validation check for the ${new Date().getTime()}`,
                html: `<h1> Hello Team, Here is the hourly data pull</h1> <br> <table><tr> <th>Hoursdata</th> <th>Book_Counts</th> <th>Search_Counts</th> <th>Hit_Counts</th> <tr><td>${element.run_hour}</td> <td>${element.book_counts}</td> <td>${element.search_counts}</td> <td>${element.hit_counts}</td></tr> </table>`
            }

            smtpTransport.sendMail(mail, function (error, response) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    console.log("Email sent");
                }
                smtpTransport.close();
            });
        }
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });

redshiftClient.close();
```

My Output for the code: (It gave the last value)

```
Hoursdata  Book_Counts  Search_Counts  Hit_Counts
2               2131        5645654       4355
```

Expected output: (I need all the value)

```
Hoursdata  Book_Counts  Search_Counts  Hit_Counts
1               23425        457474       2534
2               2131        5645654       4355
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is, iterate over all the rows and for each row send a message, while you should be creating a mail message once with all the details in html. As suggested in my previous answer, use some npm package to create html and pass it to html while creating message and after that send email.